# Corrupted HLL object with PFMERGE

Tags: redis

I have a small system that uses the HLL system in redis. This system does:

1. `GET myHll` from db0
2. `SET myHll "<hash>"` to db1
3. `PFMERGE myOtherHll myHll` in db1 to merge the 2 hll

However, I'm sometime greeted by: `(error) INVALIDOBJ Corrupted HLL object detected`

Example:

```
127.0.0.1:6379[7]> pfcount myHll
(integer) 2
127.0.0.1:6379[7]> get myHll
"HYLL\x01\x00\x00\x00\x02\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00@G\x84b\xf8\x84\\\xbc"

127.0.0.1:6379[7]> pfcount myOtherHll
(integer) 1
127.0.0.1:6379[7]> get myOtherHll
"HYLL\x01\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00\x00cA\xef\xbf\xbd\\\xef\xbf\xbd"

127.0.0.1:6379[7]> pfmerge anotherHll myOtherHll myHll
(error) INVALIDOBJ Corrupted HLL object detected
```

So my questions are:

1. Am I theorically allowed to `GET/SET` an hll hash?
2. If I am, any idea why it wouldn't work here?
3. If I'm not, do I have alternative way of doing this?

Note: I'm using redis 6.2.4

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `GET`/`SET` on an HyperLogLog hash for the purpose you mentioned is undocumented, so avoid using it that way.

Instead, I would suggest using `DUMP` to obtain a serialized value of the key from your *db0* and `RESTORE` to re-create it on your *db1*: these commands use the same RDB format Redis itself uses while persisting point-in-time snapshots of datasets to disk.

Comment: Thanks I'll try that. I'll accept your answer after I've done some test

Comment: Unfortunately, my error is now `@user_script:7: ERR DUMP payload version or checksum are wrong`... I'll triple check to make sure my java app is not transforming the string, but I highly doubt it :(

Comment: Mmm... I would try that through the redis-cli, just to exclude other possible issues.

Comment: It appears I have an issue with Lettuce and how it retrieves the dump's output which is run into a lua script. But thanks for the dump/restore hint